# How to Integrate Oracle9i with JAVA or JSP?

Tags: java, database, oracle, jsp, jdbc

I want to make a little application. That will have register, save, update, delete, login for user. This will be in JSP. I know JSP very well.
I have done some work JSP, with the MSAcess , SQL Server database with JDBC.
But I have naver ever use "Oracle" for this. But I really want to do this with Oracle 8 or 9 version. I search and found different type of method for integration.
Can you please help me for "How to Integrate Oracle with java or JSP?" if you have some examples, code , links , blog , tutorials, please share if that can help me.

**Thanks in Advance**

Comment: Just consider to upgrade to Oracle 11g or at least 10g, Oracle 8 and 9 are outdated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything else is pretty similar except that you need a different database driver. You can check out this [link](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/fcdb/oracle/or-jdbc.html#0.1_connection) and this [link](http://w2.syronex.com/jmr/edu/db/oracle-and-java). You should also read about how to tune your code for optimal performance and a good read on that topic is [here](http://www.precisejava.com/javaperf/j2ee/JDBC.htm).

This would also be a good time for you to get introduce to the DAO pattern. A good example is [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/dao-138818.html).

Comment: Thaks for your time. I am just checking these links.

Comment: hi, I am using this.
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
      "jdbc:oracle:thin:@dbaprod1:1544:SHR1_PRD", username, passwd);
But I think it require a .jar file? I don't found it. Can you please help me?

Comment: You need the ojdbc.jar file. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-10201-088211.html